# Update information on a MediaWiki page from an RSS feed?

Tags: rss, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I administer a mediawiki for a school group. We have a website that students complete projects in for virtual rewards. I want to put counters on a page of my wiki with statistical information (cumulative exp/coins, assignments completed, most productive student, etc.) about each of the seven groups that the students are divided up into. It would be simple enough if the two sites were hosted on the same server, but they are not. I figure that an RSS feed with the statistical information may be a good way to get info from website server to wiki server. How would I reference the information from the RSS feed in the wiki page?

Just to make sure my idea is clear, I would put in the feed something along the lines of:

```
[ATLAS]
exp=15000
coins=7500
eva=350
ip=150
dmg=500

[CERES]
exp=13000
;and so on
```

I would like to reference that in the wiki page. Is it doable?

Comment: Yes, that would be a quite easy extension to write. Start by having a look here: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:MediaWiki_Developer%27s_Guide

Comment: Also, the extension [External Data](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:External_Data) might be able to do the job